# How can i sum values to a pandas existing column from different dictionaries based on index?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary of multiple accounts for a user.
Every account holds float values for some keys.

i would like to sum up values from all of the accounts(dictionaries) to a single column while avoiding nested iteration, since the dictionaries are big.

before applying:

[image: before]

on the other hand i have 2 different dicts

```py
d = {
      a:{0:5,3:2,4:1},
      b:{1:4,3:1,4:10}
    }

total = pd.Series(index=list(range(6)),data=0,name='Total')

for acc in d.keys():
   for k,v in d[acc].items():
       total[k] += v
```

after summing applying code:

[image]

i would like to AVOID ITERATING all a,b keys, but don't mind to iterate 
through d.keys()

is there any way to use .map() or other efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct a dataframe from the dictionary, and use `sum` to add both columns together, and then add both dataframes using `DataFrame.add`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d, index=total.index)
total.add(df.sum(axis=1))

0     5.0
1     4.0
2     0.0
3     3.0
4    11.0
5     0.0
dtype: float64
```